# Copiar columa con desface de 14 celdas en CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, spyder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Quería pedirles ayuda, estoy intentando hacer unas lineas de python pandas, en la que busco copiar los datos de la columna [B] y pegarlo en la columna [C] pero con el desfase de 14 filas o celdas.
Este fue mi código pero no es lo que me sirve. Los datos proviene de un CSV

```
prod33["C"] = prod33['B'].rolling(14).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final nadie pudo ayudarme, pero investigando un poco encontrñé una solución que me a servido, comparto con uds por si a alguien le pueda dar uso:

```
for i in range(14,len(df)):
   df.loc[i,'C'] = df.loc[i-14,'B']
```

Comment: ‍♂️ Relajate,es solo un comentario